# Unable to make requests to Kafka container from another container using kafka-python

Tags: python, docker, apache-kafka, kafka-python

The Env:

```
services:  
  zookeeper:
      image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
      ports:
        - 2181
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      #- 8004:8004
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "foo:10:1"
      # JMX_PORT: 8004
  clickhouse-01:
      image: yandex/clickhouse-server
      hostname: clickhouse-01
      container_name: clickhouse-01
      ports:
          - 9001:9000
      volumes:
          - ./config/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
          - ./config/metrika.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/metrika.xml
          - ./config/macros/macros-01.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/macros.xml

      ulimits:
          nofile:
              soft: 262144
              hard: 262144
      depends_on:
          - "zookeeper"

  clickhouse-02:
      image: yandex/clickhouse-server
      hostname: clickhouse-02
      container_name: clickhouse-02
      ports:
          - 9002:9000
      volumes:
          - ./config/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
          - ./config/metrika.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/metrika.xml
          - ./config/macros/macros-02.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/macros.xml

      ulimits:
          nofile:
              soft: 262144
              hard: 262144
      depends_on:
          - "zookeeper"

  clickhouse-03:
      image: yandex/clickhouse-server
      hostname: clickhouse-03
      container_name: clickhouse-03
      ports:
          - 9003:9000
      volumes:
          - ./config/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
          - ./config/metrika.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/metrika.xml
          - ./config/macros/macros-03.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/macros.xml

      ulimits:
          nofile:
              soft: 262144
              hard: 262144
      depends_on:
          - "zookeeper"
```

Querying Kafka through the Zookeeper container:

```
bash-4.4# /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper zookeeper:2181
__consumer_offsets
foo
raw_trap
```

Netstat results from within the zookeeper container:

```
root@0a5f9a441da3:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.13# netstat
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0a5f9a441da3:2181       kafka_1:58622 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 0a5f9a441da3:2181       clickhouse-02.cli:60728 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 0a5f9a441da3:2181       clickhouse-01.cli:56448 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 0a5f9a441da3:2181       clickhouse-03.cli:39656 ESTABLISHED
```

Telnet from container running kafka-python to broker:

```
root@f10fe1b58fa9:~# telnet kafka 9092
Trying 172.18.0.8...
Connected to kafka.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Kafka error from telnet:

```
kafka_1           | [2019-06-23 13:38:05,350] WARN [SocketServer brokerId=1019] Unexpected error from /172.18.0.5; closing connection (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
kafka_1           | org.apache.kafka.common.network.InvalidReceiveException: Invalid receive (size = 1903520116 larger than 104857600)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:104)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:424)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:385)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:651)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:572)
kafka_1           |     at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:483)
kafka_1           |     at kafka.network.Processor.poll(SocketServer.scala:830)
kafka_1           |     at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:730)
kafka_1           |     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Error when attempting to send data to kafka topic using python:

```
>>> from kafka import KafkaProducer
>>> producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092'])
>>> producer
<kafka.producer.kafka.KafkaProducer object at 0x7ff84417b320>
>>> producer.send('foo', b'raw_bytes')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 564, in send
    self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 691, in _wait_on_metadata
    "Failed to update metadata after %.1f secs." % (max_wait,))
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
```

I've been up and down the web a few times trying to find a solution. I started with making sure the `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` from the container was correct and experimented with changing it but got nowhere. When I change the `bootstrap_servers=['kafka:9092']` entry's endpoint, I get an error:

```
>>> consumer = KafkaConsumer('foo', 
...                          group_id='test-group',
...                          bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._client = KafkaClient(metrics=self._metrics, **self.config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 239, in __init__
    self.config['api_version'] = self.check_version(timeout=check_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 865, in check_version
    raise Errors.NoBrokersAvailable()
kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable: NoBrokersAvailable
```

So it appears that I may be making the connection, but might fundamentally misunderstanding something about the request(s) I am attempting to make with the producer.

Here are the docs and the example I am using for the python library I am currently testing https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/usage.html#kafkaconsumer

EDIT: I have successfully returned messages from our production kafka environment that runs on bare metal using a consumer.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Robin Moffet’s excellent blog post on Kafka listeners and docker:

If you are using docker you need to set KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS to the external address (host or IP) so that clients can correctly connect to it. Otherwise they’ll try to connect to the internal host address–and if that’s not reachable then problems ensue.

https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Kafka client connections are actually a two step process that involved connecting to the bootstrap server first to request metadata about the entire cluster, and then connecting to one or many of the clusters nodes using the advertised listeners names and ports.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I looked into that and I probably wasn't clear that I am accessing the kafka container from inside the docker network, not from my localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to solved the problem by using a different container version:

```
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.11-0.11.0.3
```

My consumer object can now retrieve the topic list from the broker. Something I was unable to do previously.

Comment: the latest version of kafka today (June 2019) is 2.2.1 and that version is 0.11.0.3 (the 2.11 part is the scala version) so consider using a more up to date image if available.

Comment: @HansJespersen when I pull the latest version, I get the same error. I am going to pull each one and see what happens.

Comment: or possibly try the confluentinc docker images instead although some of the params may be slightly different